# NumberFormatException when using Double.parseDouble()

Tags: android, google-maps, numberformatexception

I am trying to store `LatLng` object in database by converting it into double but I am getting number format exception. Can someone help me understand what is wrong.

```
String[] latlong =  latLng.toString().split(",");
latlong[0] = latlong[0].replace("(","");
latlong[1] = latlong[1].replace(")","");
double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latlong[0]);
double longitude = Double.parseDouble(latlong[1]);
```

Here is the exception I am getting:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "lat/lng: 16.5431428"
>                                                                           at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
>                                                                            at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:269)

Comment: `"lat/lng: 16.5431428"` is not a double ... you know that for latitude and longitude   LatLng has getters?

Comment: log values before parsing . I think nonnumeric value in lat-long

Comment: there are no non numeric values , i already checked it@SuryaPrakashKushawah

Comment: *there are no non numeric values , i already checked it* ... lol, no, you didn't error says something different: *NumberFormatException: Invalid double: **"lat/lng: 16.5431428"***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this instead (assuming you are actually using Google's LatLng):

```
double latitude = latLng.latitude;
double longitude = latLng.longitude;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get `latitude` & `longitude` in `Double` from  [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng) object as below.

```
double latitude = latlng.latitude;
double longitude = latlng.longitude;
```